# Operator PlusPlus in C

Tags: c, operators

As I already know, the operator ++ has a difference between two situations:
x++, and ++x;
Though,
When I try to write such a code:

```
int x = 5;
int* y = &x;
int value;
value = *y++ + ++*y;
```

the value of value, is 12, in the end of the equation.
If I swap the equation to be

```
value = ++*y + *y++;
```

It is also 12, and I don't understand the rule.
What is he doing first?
In two cases the y pointer points to garbage.

Thanks,
Uriah.

Comment: Well, there is undefined behavior in your code. See this --> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/949433/why-are-these-constructs-using-undefined-behavior

Comment: Don't write such code, it's both cryptic and leads to undefined behavior. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: look this post there is an overview http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4176328/undefined-behavior-and-sequence-points

Answer (score 1):

This line leads to undefined behaviour:`value = *y++ + ++*y;`
*y++ is equivalent to `*(y++)`, so it increments the pointer, not the actual value.
After that, `++*y` dereferences `y` which causes undefined behaviour.

In the second example, `++*y` actually increments the value where `y` points to.
So `x` will be 6. After that `*y++` dereferences `y` which will also give 6.
So thats why 12 is calculated in the second example.
Dereferencing `y` after also causes undefined behaviour, so its best to avoid code like this.